# I want my drop-down nav bar to overlap on-top with the next content

Tags: html, css, image, dropdown, nav

I tried making this navigational bar with click drop-downs which I achieved using a checkbox, however, when I click on the the checkbox, its content drops down like a block element but I want it to sit on-top the image

```css
.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.drop-down {
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--coral);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
}

header a:hover {
  background-color: #040628;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  background-color: var(--blue);
  padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+.content {
  display: block;
}

.puzzles {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="drop-down">
    <label for="checkbox">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />

    <div class="content">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">New</a>
      <a href="#">Popular</a>
      <a href="#">Trending</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666609393250-5ddc8fa87fa9?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2Njg0MTMxNTc&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80" />
</header>
```

I was expecting the dropdown-content to overlap on the image instead of dropping down

Comment: You'll need to absolutely position it then.

Comment: @CBroe Could you elaborate

Comment: On what, exactly? Don't know what absolute positioning is? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to do, you set the `div` with the `content` class to `position:absolute` so that it gets taken out of the normal document flow so when it appears it'll appear over the top of the content. Set the parent element (in your case the `div` with class `drop-down` to `position:relative` so that the drop down is positioned relative to this element.

Kevin Powell does a good [video](https://youtu.be/P6UgYq3J3Qs) on this to get you started and there's a good [explainer](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) at CSS tricks too. Hope this helps.

```css
.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48
}


/* added css variable definitions */

 :root {
  --coral: coral;
  --blue: blue;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.drop-down {
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
  /* added this */
  position: relative;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--coral);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
}

header a:hover {
  background-color: #040628;
}

.content {
  /*added this */
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: var(--blue);
  padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+.content {
  display: block;
}

.puzzles {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
<header>
  <div class="drop-down">
    <label for="checkbox">
        Click me
      </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <div class="content">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">New</a>
      <a href="#">Popular</a>
      <a href="#">Trending</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x600?text=some+image ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the drop down position:absolute or position:fixed. It will stay on top no matter how much you scroll.